# BindingSource Filter

Tags: c#, filter, bindingsource

I am trying to set a filter to one column for two arguements to my bindingsource which is bound to a datagrid.

Here is the code I am using to try filter my two arguements:

```
string filter = string.Format("(Status LIKE '%Pending%') And (Status LIKE '%Progress%')");
bs.Filter = filter;
```

However, it doesn't seem to filter any results. But if I just use one arguement:

```
string filter = string.Format("(Status LIKE '%Pending%')");
bs.Filter = filter;
```

It filters correctly. Is there something I am missing to make it filter out two arguments instead of one?

Comment: Do you want to retrieve rows that have a status value that contains both "Pending" and "Progress"? Or do you want to retrieve rows that have a status value of either "Pending" or "Progress"?

Comment: You are using "And" operator which means "Status" must be both '%Pending%' and '%Progress%', at the same time.

Comment: I am trying to retrieve rows that contain both Pending and Progress. Would I need an OR operator instead?

Comment: Thanks guys I have sorted now.

Comment: Are you using Entity Data Framework, it seems that it doesn't work with it, I'm trying to find an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

```
string filter = string.Format("(Status LIKE '%Pending%') Or (Status LIKE '%Progress%')");
```

Worked